# Should we close questions as off-topic if the fact that it's off-topic isn't known until it's answered?

Tags: discussion

This question was prompted by [this question about a structure on a mountain in Switzerland](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66306/755) that I noticed in the review queue.

It has attracted a couple of votes to close the question as off-topic. It does turn out that the structure was not related to aviation at all, but the asker originally thought it was aviation-related, which is why they asked it here.

Someone has already answered the question, pointing out that the structure was a microwave signal reflector that is (presumably) not related to aviation.

Should we close questions as off-topic if there was reasonable cause to believe the question was actually related to aviation, but that the answer to the question shows that it was not?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to look at it.

If the question was closed *based on* the answer, it would still be a valid community decision. Being an object not related to aviation, makes it of no value to future visitors/readers. But it won't be deleted nor the reputation points taken away. And the asker's question was answered. (No harmed parties.)

The second way to look at it is how I voted to close:

Right from the get go before the answer I didn't think it's on-topic. I only voted to close – by then an answer was posted – when I had formed my logic.

Here is the question format:

1. Is object A related to aviation?
2. If it is, does it utilize X or Y? (Bullets and video-based system.)

The same question can be asked for literally anything. You see a weird structure on Google Earth near an airport for example, and ask (1) and (2).

While research is not required [for aviation questions], it is required to make sure (1) is on-topic before asking (2). In other words: Why single out the Aviation site for (1)? On the Skeptics site they only allow substantial claims (no claims from your buddies). We're more relaxed here; my point here is verifying the on-topic-ness can't be an on-topic question (chat can be used).

---

I'd like to take a moment to explain how one asker can *easily* turn such a question into a good one:

First, apply Occam's razor. If actual bullets are used, *who* is going to climb a summit each time to verify and replace the huge paper target – why not simply go somewhere more... flat. If not bullets, how is a video-based (laser) system going to account for trajectory.

When the premise seems to be sketchy, zoom out to the more generic topic . . .

. . . and casually slip in what you saw. Zooming out means asking how do modern-day pilots train to aim their bullets on ground targets (interesting topic that was once covered in a RCAF training documentary/reality show). And the answer to that question *will* show the kind and orientation of targets used. Slipping in the object would be, "and do they have special equipment used for mountain summit targets?" Here the Q&A will benefit a lot more people googling the topic or browsing the site.